# How to optimize pagination in WordPress？ sometimes it takes 2 or 3 seconds

Tags: mysql, wordpress, explain

Enter a fixed category(term_taxonomy_id = 262)
A SQL LIKE that：

```
    SELECT   wp_posts.ID     
    FROM wp_posts  LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships 
    ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)     
    WHERE 1=1  AND (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (262)) 
    AND ((wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')))     
    GROUP BY wp_posts.ID     
    ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC     
    LIMIT 0, 15;
```

and the sql explain is:
[explain sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioSm1.png)
Reduce SQL query time

Comment: add an index on `(post_type,post_status )`

Comment: This is not a valid SQL query. Queries never start with FROM.

Comment: oh,i edited it, now it is.

Comment: That's not a left join. The predicate `wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (262)` silently converts it into an inner join.